# Test Cases Method in c# .Net Worker Service

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I'm new to doing unit testing in c# and trying to understand how to do test cases using NUnit in a worker service and I don't know how to replicate it so it tests the same as the method. This is a service that runs and sends SMS's in the background of a computer.

IMessagingInfo.cs - this is the model that I retrieve the information from

```
public interface IMessagingInfo
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    DateTime? APPT_DATE { get; set; }

    string Location { get; set; }

    string TreatmentLocation { get; set; }
    
    string Ward { get; set; }

    string APPT_START { get; set; }

    Guid? ApptId { get; set; }

    string MobilePhone { get; set; }

}
```

TwilioHandler.cs: - this is  the method that will check to ensure the values from the database are correct and have values so that the service doesn't send blank information in a text.

```
public bool CheckModelFieldsValid(IMessagingInfo item)
    {

        if(item == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //implement this later as the mobile phone numbers have some that are null in DB
       // if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.MobilePhone))
       //{
       //   return false;
       // }
       // 

        if (item.APPT_START == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.TreatmentLocation))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Location))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Ward))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (item.ApptId == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This is what I have so far in TwilioHandlerTests.cs where I dont understand the logistics of Unit testing on how to set up the framework and test cases.

```
public class Tests
{
    //dbcontext, TwilioHandler, TwilioAccount
    private Mock<DbContextConn> _MockDbContext;
    private Mock<IOptions<TwilioAccount>> _mockoptions;
    private Mock<ILogger<TwilioHandler>> _mockLogger;
    TwilioHandler _twh;

    private Mock<IMessagingInfo> _MessagingInfoMock = new Mock<IMessagingInfo>();


    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _MockDbContext = new Mock<DbContextConn>();
        _mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger<TwilioHandler>>();
        _mockoptions = new Mock<IOptions<TwilioAccount>>();
        //inmemorydatabase routine to add records 
    }
    [Test]
    public void CheckTwilioAccount_ModelFields_Valid_Test()
    {
     //want to replicate method here
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: So, basically you want to test the validator. I am growing to like [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/). Makes the validators very well [testable](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/testing.html). (I am _not_ affiliated to the project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already suggested to use FluentValidation, but if you do not want to do that,
you can make this very much easier to test.

If you look at it, validating the DTO is not really a concern of the `TwilioHandler` (at least it should not be). So why not factor it out into it's own class?

Then you can easily test that class / method without the need to mock any dependency of `TwilioHandler`.

All you need to do then is create the possible cases*) you expect to cause the validation to fail and check if they do. And vice versa create a representative sample of cases that should pass and check if they do.

*) Instances that model those cases. For example an instance that has `item == null`.

Example:

```
[Test]
void Validation_should_fail_if_item_is_null()
{
    bool expected = false;
// Assuming the Validator class is called "IMessagingInfoValidator", and there has been 
// setup a testsubject Instance named "ItemNullInstance".
    bool actual = new IMessagingInfoValidator().Validate(ItemNullInstance);
    Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```

For the other properties, you would write respective tests.

Comment: I'm going to follow this and try understand it better. Thank you for your reply as this seems alot more understandable now!

Comment: How to mock a web API call? `using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(_configuration["Razer:Production"], content, ct);` @Fildor

Comment: That wasn't the point here,  @Cenk